# Have I found a bug in Java? Regarding AttributeSet

Tags: java, swing, coding-style, jtextpane

I've been using a JTextPane (or my sub-classed version of one) in an application I've been writing, and so I've been working with Styles. My program wasn't acting the way I wanted, and I tracked the behavior to what I think is a bug in the AttributeSet.containsAttributes(AttributeSet attributes) method. I wrote the following short program to illustrate it:

```
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.Style;

public class StyleBug {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setText("This is a test string");

        Style bold = textPane.addStyle(BOLD, null);
        StyleConstants.setBold(bold, true);

        Style italic = textPane.addStyle(ITALIC, null);
        StyleConstants.setItalic(italic, true);

        int start = 5;
        int end = 10;

        textPane.getStyledDocument().setCharacterAttributes(start, end - start, textPane.getStyle(BOLD), false);
        textPane.getStyledDocument().setCharacterAttributes(start, end - start, textPane.getStyle(ITALIC), false);

        for(int i = start; i < end; i++)
            System.out.println(textPane.getStyledDocument().getCharacterElement(i).getAttributes()
            .containsAttributes(textPane.getStyle(BOLD))); //all print false
    }

    private static final String BOLD = "Bold";
    private static final String ITALIC = "Italic";
}
```

Is this a bug, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you referring to your static initializations?

Comment: textPane.getStyle(BOLD) and textPane.getStyle(ITALIC),

Comment: @Mikaveli, the bug I am referring to is that the containsAttributes method says that the text isn't bolded, even though I applied a style with the Bold attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I comment out this line:

```
// textPane.getStyledDocument().setCharacterAttributes(start, end - start, textPane.getStyle(ITALIC), false);
```

Then it prints true for all of the elements. According to the Javadoc for `setCharacterAttributes` it uses all of the Attributes from the Style you are passing in, so you are simply overriding the `BOLD` selection with the `ITALIC` selection.

EDIT:

I pulled up the debugger and got this array of attributes for `getCharacterElement(5)`.

```
[0] javax.swing.text.StyleConstants$FontConstants "italic"
[1] java.lang.Boolean "true"
[2] javax.swing.text.StyleConstants "name"
[3] java.lang.String "Italic"
[4] javax.swing.text.StyleConstants$FontConstants "bold"
[5] java.lang.Boolean "true"
```

As you can see, the attributes are ordered in groups of 2. `italic` is set to true, `bold` is set to true, and the `name` is set to `"Italic"`. This likely means that only one name is allowed for a named attribute set for a character. Note that the unnamed attributes were merged correctly, so it is behaviourally what you want even if you can't see if a particular named attribute is applied to a character.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out with this.

Yes, I noticed that as well. But I expected it to maintain the bold attribute when I added the italic attribute. The fourth parameter I use in setCharacterAttributes is supposed to determine whether the new attributes overwrite the old ones or are merged with them.

From Javadoc:
boolean replace - indicates whether or not the previous attributes should be cleared before the new attributes as set. If true, the operation will replace the previous attributes entirely. If false, the new attributes will be merged with the previous attributes.

Comment: (sorry, this is my first time posting)

Comment: @Mark I have edited my answer now that you have pointed that out. It looks like you can't rely on the name of the Style if you are going to merge the Styles together (which makes sense).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You were absolutely right about it being behaviorally correct; when I viewed the JTextPane those characters were both bolded and italicized. It seems to me like they should change that behavior, so that the name of the Style isn't counted as an Attribute, but whatever. I will post my work around below. Thanks again for all your help. Could you tell me how you pulled up the debugger and got that information? I've never seen that kind of thing before.

Comment: @Mark I was using http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/ as my IDE. I set a breakpoint near the end and used the "Evaluate Expression" function (Alt+F8) to evaluate `textPane.getStyledDocument().getCharacterElement(5)`. It then gave me a tree of all contained elements, and one was a variable named `attributes` that was of type `Object[]`.

Comment: Thanks, I've never heard of that IDE before. I'll have to take a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

Bringer128 found the problem above, but I'll just clarify a little more.

When a Style is added to a JTextPane, the String that is passed as an argument is actually placed in the Style as an Attribute (not surprisingly, the NameAttribute). When the Style is applied to a range of characters, the NameAttribute is applied along with any other Attributes that have been set on the Style. So when my BOLD Style was applied, every character in that range had its BoldAttribute set to true and its NameAttribute set to "Bold". Then, when my ITALIC Style was applied, every character had its ItalicAttribute set to true, and then its NameAttribute set to "Italic". Then, when containsAttributes() checked if all Attributes in my BOLD Style were applied to those characters, it returned false because their NameAttributes had been changed from "Bold" to "Italic". I hope that didn't confuse anyone.

Here is my work around (I think it's actually simpler than the original code). The gist of it is I never use Styles or JTextPane.addStyle() at all; I just keep constant MutableAttributeSets.

```
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.MutableAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;

public class StyleBugFix {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setText("This is a test string");

        StyleConstants.setBold(BOLD, true);

        StyleConstants.setItalic(ITALIC, true);

        int start = 5;
        int end = 10;

        textPane.getStyledDocument().setCharacterAttributes(start, end - start, BOLD, false);
        textPane.getStyledDocument().setCharacterAttributes(start, end - start, ITALIC, false);
        for(int i = start; i < end; i++)
            System.out.println(textPane.getStyledDocument().getCharacterElement(i).getAttributes()
                .containsAttributes(BOLD)); //all now print true
    }

    private static final MutableAttributeSet BOLD = new SimpleAttributeSet();
    private static final MutableAttributeSet ITALIC = new SimpleAttributeSet();
}
```

Thanks again to Bringer128 for all his help.

Comment: +1 for posting the final solution as an answer. This should help anyone else that runs into this.